# py2exe cannot import from six.py

Tags: python, py2exe, six-python

I'm trying use py2exe on a program that imports `urlparse` from `six.moves.urllib_parse`. Here is the program:

```
# hello.py
from six.moves.urllib_parse import urlparse
print('hello world')
```

And here is my setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['hello.py'])
```

Running hello.py works fine. When I compile hello.py into an exe using `python setup.py py2exe`, a `hello.exe` file is produced. However, when I run `hello.exe` I get an error saying:

`ImportError: No module named urlparse`

I'm using Python 2.7.

With Python 3.4, I get an error saying `KeyError: 'six.moves'` when running `python setup.py py2exe`.

How can I stop these errors from occurring?

Comment: I would try with adding 'six' to the py2exe 'packages' option

Comment: @Werner That gives the error: "TypeError: six is not a package"

Comment: Since py2exe creates an exe for a specific python version, I decided to replace all my instances of six. Doing so fixed this error for me. (However I then ran into other import errors)

Comment: Oops, realized that later, and I tried 'includes' for 'six' but that didn't work either.

Comment: @Humdinger, what do you mean replacing all your 'six' instances?  Did you upgrade to a newer version and that fixed that issue with py2exe?

Comment: @Werner I mean, in my code, whenever I am using a library from six, I instead replace the `import six` to import the python 3 version of the same module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

py2exe released a new version recently that fixes this problem:

```
Changes in version 0.9.2.2:
- Added support for six, cffi, pycparser, openssl.
```

Using this version I was able to create an .exe and run it successfully.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is just that py2exe doesn't detect the modules that are proxied through six, so they're not bundled.

All you have to do is add the module in question (urlparse) to your includes in your setup.py:

```
  options={
      "py2exe": {
      ...
      "includes": ["urlparse"],
      ...
```

That way the module will be packaged, and when six tries to import it, it will work.